# Relationship with two APIs (nodejs, angular, express, mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, express

I am a beginner in angular / node and I have a question that maybe can be simple (I believe) ...

I was following the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial and started to wonder if it would be possible to have a type of "Contract"

Contract would receive the data of the api Hero (id, name ...) and also data of another api "Company" (id, name, location ...) and then join everything in a called api "Contract".

Then in that case I could list "Contract ID" or "contract number", and see the information (which company, which hero, that kind of thing)

Is it possible to do this with node, angular and mysql? if it is ... Could you show me some example or tutorial to follow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible and easy, you just need a few things set up:

1. Your db needs a `contract` table (assuming you want a many to many relationship between heroes and companies) where you set foreign keys to the `hero_id` and the `company_id`.
2. You need a new endpoint in your server that receives the `contractId` as a parameter and then you can do a request to your mysql db that uses your contract table to join the company to the hero, i.e.

   `SELECT * FROM hero AS h 
          JOIN contract AS cont ON h.id = cont.hero_id
          JOIN company AS comp ON comp.id = cont.company_id
      WHERE cont.id = ? ;`

(replace the `?` with the contract id you receive from the endpoint, ideally using prepared statements for mysql or a similar solution like the one [mysqljs provides](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values))

Angular will just need to call the new endpoint with a `contractId` parameter and you should receive the data if it exists.